# Android How to overlap a view like this

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to create a overlap view like this when i select a option.

The root layout is Linear layout with horizontal orientation  and each item is aligned with weight.

Each item is a **imageview**. How do i add a view under that imageview that should **overlap** the root layout like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `FrameLayout`, and add your existing `LinearLayout` to it. Then, duplicate the `LinearLayout` and add your round `ImageViews`to that layout, which should now be on top of your original `LinearLayout`. Show/hide the rounded `ImageViews` as necessary.